# Request to merge ggplot tag with the ggplot2 tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) tag has 2500+ questions, while [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) has only around 125. They both refer to the same graphing package in the R statistical programming language. The proper name of the package is in fact ggplot2, and that is the only version currently available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

The name ggplot2 is a little misleading, as it implies there's a version 1 out there, but that's not really the case. I've never seen a single question on SO that is specific to the original ggplot package, and the earliest question tagged [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) was asked well after ggplot2 was released. (And regardless, ggplot2 itself has undergone several major updates that have required significant code changes anyway. So everything should really be under just one tag.)

I have tried to remove the [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) tag whenever I see it, but that's getting tiresome. Can we please get some help from a moderator with merging the two?

Comment: Just because it's the only version currently available doesn't mean there was't once a ggplot 1? Was there? Is it possible some questions were asked against that before 2 came out?

Comment: @Caleb That ship has sailed. There have been at least 3 major releases with significant code changes that are all covered under the ggplot2 tag. The oldest question with the ggplot tag is from Sep 2011, well after ggplot2 was released. I personally have never seen any question on SO that is specific to code that old.

Comment: Well then it sounds like a merge candidate to me. Maybe you can add that extra background to the question so a moderator coming along to handle it doesn't have the same doubts I did if they didn't know the software in question.

Comment: `ggplot` is also the name of the main function of the `ggplot2` package, which is presumably why its tag gets used now and again. They should be merged, for sure.